# Print keywords associated with a dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So, I have a function that is supposed to ask the user to input the name of a continent, then the function should go through Dictionary["values"] to find the continent and then search through all of the countries in dictionary["keywords"] to print all of the countries in the list that are in the continent.

dictionary["values"] = a list of continents
dictionary["keywords"] = a list of countries

So far I have:

```
def filterCountriesByContinent(self):
    continentinp =  input(str("Please enter a continent: ")) #user input
    if continentinp  in  self.Dictionary["values"]: #check if input in Dictionary.values
        return print(self.Dictionary["keywords"]) #if in Dictionary.values, print off associated countries
    else:
        return print("That country is not in the Dictionary")
```

Right now it is just printing off the whole list of countries in Dictionary["keywords"] including ones that aren't in the input continent.

Comment: don't you have a mapping of continents to countries?

Comment: `print(self.Dictionary["keywords"])` will always print the same thing. Shouldn't it be related somehow to `continentinp` ?

Comment: In a previous function we take the input of a txt file, split the data into parts and associate those parts with Dictionary["values"] and Dictionary["keywords"]. I'm trying to figure out how to relate them in order to create a different print section that works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a dictionary of continents and their countries first. It should look something like this.

```
{
  "North America": [
    "United States of America",
    "Canada",
    "Cuba",
    "Mexico"
  ],
  "South America": [
    "Brazil",
    "Argintina"
  ],
  "Europe": [
    "United Kingdom",
    "Germany"
  ],
  "Africa": [
    "Egypt"
  ]
}
```

Then the Python code is like this.

```
dict_of_cont = # here is your dictionary
continent = raw_input("Enter the continent you wish to list the countries of: ")
for cont in dict_of_cont[continent.lower()]: # loop through the countries.
  print(cont + " is in " + continent.lower())
```

However note that you must spell the country right to get any results.

Comment: Would you happen to know a function that could take inputs such as China,Asia
United States of America,North America
Brazil,South America
Japan,Asia
Canada,North America
Indonesia,Asia
Nigeria,Africa
Mexico,North America
Egypt,Africa
France,Europe
Italy,Europe
South Africa,Africa
South Korea,Asia
Colombia,South America

and gather all the ones of the same continent into a dictionary like the one you showed? Note the list of countries and continents provided is a txt file with each country,continent set on a different line.

Comment: You could try using CSV for this, [link here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) Then strip the file by newlines (`str.strip("\n")`), then for each value appended it to a dictionary of continents. If you want me to put an example in the answer please edit your question.